# Fulltext search using contains in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

i am using full text search concept in sql server 2008, but facing some problem in contains..
Suppose i have searched with keyword 'Life' it returns 'The Life and Death of Buildings' in first 20 records but i want it return 'life' first then 'The Life and Death of Buildings'
Thanks...

Comment: I don't understand your question fully, it would help to post some sample data rows and the result you expect. Specifically, do you have rows in the table with just the word "life", or do you want to put "life" as the first row in your result set even if it doesn't match any rows? I suspect you want to use it as a header for your output, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This will be much inefficient but here it is one solution:

```
select column_name  from table_name where column_name like 'Life%' union 
select column_name  from table_name where column_name like '%Life%';
```

plus it will fetch distinct entries only.

Comment: There is no `ORDER BY` in your query so you can't guarantee that the rows will be in any particular order. And the OP wants to use `CONTAINS` rather than `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

Contains will searches for the word life in the column and if it matches it will return the result, Use order by in it

check out this link for more info 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258227(v=sql.80).aspx

Thanks,Arun